style zoom:50% dragula position manipulation
It is necessary for the vue2 web application to be scaled. We use dragula to realize assignments of elements via drag&drop.
Unfortunately, the position of the elements during the drag is calculated with the factor 0.5 -> zoom:50%.
Is there a way to tell dragula this factor or to manipulate the lib from outside in the calculation?
Unfortunately the docs dont give any hint about that. So my first approach was to override the drag function... without any result:
this.dragElement = dragula(containers, {});
this.dragElement.drag = (e) => {
  //overrite the base implementation
  ...
}

